# How can I include my existing table into my export function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am relatively new to React-JS and was wondering how I could pass my variables to my **export** function. I am using the **jsPDF** library.

At the time the **Summary** page is showing up, every thing is already in the database.

The **Summary** page creates in every round an **IdeaTable** component, writes it into an array and renders it bit by bit if the users click on the **Next** button (***showNextTable()***).

This component can use a **JoinCode** & **playerID** to assemble the table that was initiated by this player.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Box, Button } from "grommet";
import IdeaTable from "../playerView/subPages/ideaComponents/IdeaTable";
import QuestionBox from "./QuestionBox";
import { FormUpload } from 'grommet-icons';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

export class Summary extends Component {
  state = {
    shownTable: 0
  };

  showSummary = () => {};

  showNextTable = () => {
    const { players } = this.props;
    const { shownTable } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      shownTable: (shownTable + 1) % players.length
    });
  };

  exportPDF = () => {

    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

    doc.text(20,20, " Test string ");

    doc.setFont('courier');

    doc.setFontType('bold');

    doc.save("generated.pdf");
  };

  render() {
    const { topic, players } = this.props;
    const { shownTable } = this.state;

    const tables = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      const player = players[i];
      const table = (
        <Box pad={{ vertical: "large", horizontal: "medium" }}>
          <IdeaTable authorID={player.id} />
        </Box>
      );
      tables.push(table);
    }

    return (
      <Box
        style={{ wordWrap: "break-word" }}
        direction="column"
        gap="medium"
        pad="small"
        overflow={{ horizontal: "auto" }}
      >
 <QuestionBox question={topic} />
        {tables[shownTable]}
        <Button
          primary
          hoverIndicator="true"
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          onClick={this.showNextTable}
          label="Next"
        />
        < br />
        <Button 
          icon={ <FormUpload color="white"/> }
          primary={true}
          hoverIndicator="true"
          style={{ 
            width: "30%",
            background: "red",
            alignSelf: "center"
        }}
          onClick={this.exportPDF}
          label="Export PDF"
        />
      </Box>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  topic: state.topicReducer.topic,
  players: state.topicReducer.players
});
const mapDispatchToProps = null;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Summary);
```

So basically how could I include the **IdeaTable** to work with my pdf export?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use html module of jsPDF you'll need a reference to generated DOM node.
See [Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) on how to get those.

Alternatively, if you want to construct PDF yourself, you would use data (e.g. from state or props), not the component references.

Related side note:
On each render of the parent component you are creating new instances for all possible `IdeaTable` in a for loop, and all are the same, and most not used. Idiomatically, this would be better:

```
state = {
  shownPlayer: 0
};
```

Instead of `{tables[shownTable]}` you would have:

```
<Box pad={{ vertical: "large", horizontal: "medium" }}>
  <IdeaTable authorID={shownPlayer} ref={ideaTableRef}/>
</Box>
```

And you get rid of the for loop.

This way, in case you use html dom, you only have one reference to DOM to store.
In case you decide to use data to generate pdf on your own, you just use `this.props.players[this.state.shownPlayer]`

In case you want to generate pdf for all **IdeaTables**, even the ones not shown, than you can't use API that needs DOM. You can still use your `players` props to generate your own PDF, or you can consider something like [React-Pdf](https://react-pdf.org/)